# Number is not a Number?

Tags: c#, numbers

For some reason when I run the "test" method, I am getting a false result.  I used some of the code from my other question about random number generation, which I have confirmed does work, but with additional safety checks.

```
public class strUtls
{
    public void test()
    {
        var maybe = 40000000f * 40000000f;
        bool number = isNumber(maybe);
    }

    public bool isNumber(object O)
    {
        // INT16,INT32,INT64,DOUBLE,FLOAT
        if (upper(O.GetType().ToString()).Contains("INT") || upper(O.GetType().ToString()).Contains("DOUBLE") || upper(O.GetType().ToString()).Contains("FLOAT"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string upper(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                s = s.Replace(s[i], upper(s[i]));
            }

            return s;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }

    private char upper(char S)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
            case ('a'):
                return 'A';
                break;
            case ('b'):
                return 'B';
                break;
            case ('c'):
                return 'C';
                break;
            case ('d'):
                return 'D';
                break;
            case ('e'):
                return 'E';
                break;
            case ('f'):
                return 'F';
                break;
            case ('g'):
                return 'G';
                break;
            case ('h'):
                return 'H';
                break;
            case ('i'):
                return 'I';
                break;
            case ('j'):
                return 'J';
                break;
            case ('k'):
                return 'K';
                break;
            case ('l'):
                return 'L';
                break;
            case ('m'):
                return 'M';
                break;
            case ('n'):
                return 'N';
                break;
            case ('p'):
                return 'O';
                break;
            case ('o'):
                return 'P';
                break;
            case ('q'):
                return 'Q';
                break;
            case ('r'):
                return 'R';
                break;
            case ('s'):
                return S;
                break;
            case ('t'):
                return 'T';
                break;
            case ('u'):
                return 'U';
                break;
            case ('v'):
                return 'V';
                break;
            case ('w'):
                return 'W';
                break;
            case ('x'):
                return 'X';
                break;
            case ('y'):
                return 'Y';
                break;
            case ('z'):
                return 'Z';
                break;
            default:
                return s;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a crazy idea. I'm not rightly sure what to make of it.

Comment: why are you rewriting the built in functions?

Comment: case ('s'): return S; Don't you mean return 'S'; ?

Comment: In my career I always learned to create minimal test cases when reporting a problem instead of asking "Here's my code, what's wrong with it?"

Comment: Why not use String.toUpper()? So many things wrong...

Comment: This code is wrong on so many levels... `case ('s'): return S;`, for a start :S

Comment: @Raging Dave: please don't use `O` (as well as `I` and `l`) as variable name ever. It is hard to distinguish from 0 and 1 for most regular fonts. (obviously barring writing code in pure 133t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying the madness a little, The easiest way to find your answer is to examine the contents of the string. Others have already outlined the correct approach now. I'm just posting this to give you an idea of a better way to structure the same code. String already has a ToUpper() Method, by the way.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var maybe = 40000000f * 40000000f;
        Console.WriteLine(isNumber(maybe));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static bool isNumber(object O)
    {
        var s = O.GetType().ToString().ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine(s); // prints "SINGLE"
        // this is silly
        //return (s.Contains("INT") || s.Contains("DOUBLE") || s.Contains("SINGLE"));
        // better
        return O is int || O is Int64 || O is float || O is double; // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: The `s.Contains("INT")` part is still wrong... `int`/`double`/`float` are C# aliases, not .Net types (which are `Int32`/`Double`/`Single`)

Comment: Yes, of course. It should be `return O is int || O is float || O is double; /* ...etc */`

Comment: The main problem I'm having is that I need to convert ANY type into a number, be it String, int16/32/64/float/double.  I'm doing input validation for a banking application and I do not know what type the UI is going to pass in.  I have not been given specs on this, but I've seen both String and Float types come in.  I think I'm going to have to use tryparse for strings.

Answer (score 5):

The actual type name of a C# `float` is `Single`, which is why your check for a float is failing.  A more straightforward test would be to use `is` or direct `Type` comparisons:

```
private static HashSet<Type> validNumericTypes = new HashSet<Type> { 
    typeof(int), typeof(uint), typeof(short), typeof(ushort), typeof(long),
    // etc.
};

// ...

return validNumericTypes.Contains(O.GetType());
```

Of course, I don't know why you *have to* test that C# does arithmetic operations correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
public bool IsNumber(object o) 
{ 
    return o is Int16 || o is Int32 || o is Int64 || o is Double || o is Single;
}
```

Or

```
public bool IsNumber(object o) 
{ 
    return o is short || o is int || o is long || o is double || o is float;
}
```

---

You can change the case of a string like this:

```
string s = "Hello World";
string upper = s.ToUpper();
string lower = s.ToLower();
```

EDIT: If you still want to implement your own `Upper` method as an exercise, do not treat each letter individually but calculate its value. Each character has a corresponding numeric value. E.g. `(int)'A' == 65`. Arithmetical operations are not defined on the type `char`, however, C# automatically converts the characters to `int` in order to allow the operations. Therefore the result must be casted back to `char`.

```
private char Upper(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        return (char)(ch + 'A' - 'a');
    }
    return ch;
}
```

We can avoid costly string concatenations if we convert the string to a character array

```
private string Upper(string s)
{
    var characters = s.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++) {
        characters[i] = Upper(characters[i]);
    }
    return new String(characters);
}
```

---

```
if (<boolean expression>) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Can simply be expressed as

```
return <boolean expression>;
```

Because the Boolean expression results in a value of type `bool`, this value can immediately be returned. You do not write

```
if (x * y == 0) {
    return 0;
} else if (x * y == 1) {
    return 1;
} else if (x * y == 2) {
    return 2;
} else if (x * y == 3) {
    return 3;
} ....
```

You simply write

```
return x * y;
```

Comment: Note that this is currently missing the unsigned types (including `byte`).

Comment: `var maybe = 40000000f * 40000000f;` will always be a `float` anyway. Even if it should evaluate to `Single.NaN` it would be of type `float`. A useful test would be `!Single.IsInfinity(maybe) && !Single.IsNaN(maybe)`.

Comment: I added an example of a own `Upper` implementation as didactic play.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong.

Don't test your types with hard-coded strings like that. Use

```
if (O is int)
{       
}

if (O is float)
{
}
```

instead.

And `float` is actually the C# alias for `System.Single`, which is actually the (one of the) problem of your code.

---

For the sake of completeness:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    s = s.Replace(s[i], upper(s[i]));
}

return s;
```

must be replaced by

```
s = s.ToUpper();
```

Also,

```
case ('s'):
    return S;
    break;
```

should be replaced by

```
case ('s'):
    return 'S';
    break;
```

which actually should be replaced by

```
case ('s'):
    return 'S';
```

which **should (must) be totally dropped from your program** because of the `.ToUpper()` built-in method. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Another advice: don't name your variables `O` nor `S`, but give them a meaningful name instead.

Answer (score 2):

For isNumber, you should try using Double.TryParse. i.e.

```
double val;
return Double.TryParse(O.toString(), out val);
```

This should return true for any value that can be converted to a double, including Int, Single/Double, or String if it can be parsed as a number.

Comment: Good answer if the input is a string. If it's not a string, then you would want to check for type first like in Olivier Jacot-Descombes's answer

Comment: This will not work. `TryParse` converts strings, containing a number, not objects.

Comment: This is the only answer that solves the original task in the best way. The other answers just fixes the different symptoms of bad coding in the first place.